# How to delete and recreate databases in postgreSQL (error: template1 being already used)

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL with python/django and windows7.

I dropped a database from `pgAdmin4`. Maybe this isn't the correct way to delete a database. Maybe I nedd to do something more to sever the connection?

Anyway now I want to recreate the database but when I do (from `pgAdmin4`) I receive the error:

```
ERROR:  database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I restarted the server, even reboot the pc but I continue to receive that error. I don't know which session is using template1, maybe is my old (and deleted) database? Maybe is this (first one):

[image: mypic]

Where SQL (partially visible on the pic) is:

```
SELECT cl.relkind, COALESCE(cin.nspname, cln.nspname) as nspname,
    COALESCE(ci.relname, cl.relname) as relname, cl.relname as indname
FROM pg_class cl
JOIN pg_namespace cln ON cl.relnamespace=cln.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_index ind ON ind.indexrelid=cl.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class ci ON ind.indrelid=ci.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_namespace cin ON ci.relnamespace=cin.oid
WHERE cl.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=10::oid) AND cl.oid > 13317::oid
UNION ALL SELECT 'n', null, nspname, null
    FROM pg_namespace nsp
    WHERE nsp.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=10::oid) AND nsp.oid > 13317::oid
UNION ALL SELECT CASE WHEN typtype='d' THEN 'd' ELSE 'y' END, null, typname, null
    FROM pg_type ty
    WHERE ty.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=10::oid) AND ty.oid > 13317::oid
UNION ALL SELECT 'C', null, conname, null
    FROM pg_conversion co
    WHERE co.oid IN (SELECT objid FROM pg_shdepend WHERE refobjid=10::oid) AND co.oid > 13317::oid
UNION ALL SELECT CASE
```

I yet don't know how to use database, so I have no idea to what to do. Should I terminate that session?

I tried from the SQL shell but this is the first times I use it so I'm not sure to have done the things in the correct way. In particular I'm not connected like postgres but like gm (a superuser).

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5433]:
Username [postgres]: gm
Inserisci la password per l'utente gm:
psql (12.1)
```

I tried the comand:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'elenconomi_db';
```

where `elenconomi_db` is the database I deleted, so it don't exist anymore and the comand gives error

So I tried `postgres=# \list` (sorry for the italian, I don't know why it's writing in italian):

```
                                          Lista dei database
   Nome    | Proprietario | Codifica |    Ordinamento     |       Ctype        |
 Privilegi di accesso
-----------+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres     | UTF8     | Italian_Italy.1252 | Italian_Italy.1252 |

 template0 | postgres     | UTF8     | Italian_Italy.1252 | Italian_Italy.1252 |
 =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |                    |                    |
 postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres     | UTF8     | Italian_Italy.1252 | Italian_Italy.1252 |
 =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |                    |                    |
 postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 righe)
```

I read is better to do not drop template1, so I ask before to `DROP DATABASE template1;`. Should I do?

And for the next time there is a better way to drop a database and recreate it?

I saw many question like this but I can't find a solution working for me.

Comment: You shouldn't be dropping template1 to begin with. Why do you want to do that? You already dropped the database you wanted to get rid off, so just create a new empty one.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need to close the session using template1... sorry, I know nothing about database but I need to solve this problem. I can't create a new one because template1 is used by something. Read first part of the question where I explain.

Comment: Maybe your own connection is to template1? The connect to the `postgres` database and create the new database. But do **NOT** drop `template1`

Comment: Ok. I will not. It'just that when you are desperated you search the solution everywhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the database session that is connected to `template1`. Then `CREATE DATABASE` will succeed.

To find and close the session, use

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'template1';
```

Comment: Ok, it worked thank you, but for the next time there is a better way to drop a database (and close the connection to template1) or using pgAdmin is fine and I need each time to write the command in your answer? Or maybe this time the connection has be left open for unknow reason

Comment: You probably clicked on `template1` in pgAdmin. Then it opens a connection. Normally programs don't connect to that database.

Comment: "For the next time there is a better way to drop a database"? Well yes. First sign-in to Postgres database.  Back the target database then rename it. Create the new database and populate from the renamed database as needed. Drop the renamed database,but keep the backup for a period of time.