# postgresql one line bash command to remove other session using the database

Tags: database, postgresql, shell, postgresql-9.4

I need your help to make something like that

[How to delete and recreate databases in postgreSQL (error: template1 being already used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196069/how-to-delete-and-recreate-databases-in-postgresql-error-template1-being-alrea)

but in one line using debian shell. I tried this:

```
su - postgres -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'imedig-cloud' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();"
```

but I get the following errors:

```
-su: -c: línea 0: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
-su: -c: línea 0: `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'imedig-cloud' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();'
```

BR...

Comment: hello @zegarek, using your command throw me several errors, from every option I pass in the line (-U, -h, -p, ...). But I finally find the solution so I edit the post and I add the command line that help me. BR and thanks for your help

Comment: Don't edit your answer into the question. If that's the answer, [post it as one and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.). And again: attach the error messages you get, in the question - don't just mention you're getting them. Those messages allow this thread to be indexed for other people to find and try your solution if they search using the same or similar error message as their search phrase.

Comment: @zegarek I´m sorry. The post has been edited to meet the requirements. I have not found how to edit my previous comment to include the errors when executing the code

Answer (score 1):

After some help from Zegarek and some research the following code make the job:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c \"SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'imedig-cloud' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();\"" postgres
```